# Webrtc on mobile browsers without a standalone app?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, webrtc

Are there webrtc demos in a state where it can behave well on a mobile browser, without using a native OS App for android and iOS?

I found this demo from [Mozilla Hacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rWPZZeXK6g4&feature=youtu.be&t=1m30s) where they can connect to a browser, through a webpage portal. If you rewind a bit you can see a contact list. I'm assuming this is also written in javascript. Is there any demos out there like this? The video is old and after hunting I haven't found anything close to this in open source.

Answer (score 1):

iOS - at the moment you're probably out of luck without an app.
Android - sure, plenty (most in fact) will work on Chrome or Firefox.  Some may be laid out better for mobile than others.  You can use https://appear.in/, [https://talky.io/](https://Talky.io/) and (with a little more pain) https://apprtc.appspot.com/